# PendingIntent cause Error

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a BroadcastReceiver which gets data from Activity by Intent, with PendingIntent. The code work fine but when i'm restarting my device and onReceive calling i am getting Error...
I don't know what the error because he appear after my phone restarting and the logchat cannot notice the phone and i don't see the error...

Activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(addOne.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
 intent.putExtra("msg", title.getText().toString());
 intent.putExtra("note", note.getText().toString());

AlarmManager alarmMgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Receiver:

```
String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
String note=intent.getStringExtra("note");

Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, alarmDialog.class);                                
startIntent.putExtra("msg",msg);
startIntent.putExtra("note",note);
startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tried change the FLAG to FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT still nothing changed.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think, may be there where error comes due to activity not starting after restart your phone and receiver still try to receive your string messages.

I don't know, How you can solve your this problem. when your phone restart your receiver gets null value. Try to use shared preference or String buffer to store your receiver String value.

remove this code

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(addOne.this,AlarmReceiver.class);
     intent.putExtra("msg", title.getText().toString());
     intent.putExtra("note", note.getText().toString());
```

try this

```
      Intent i = new Intent("my.action.string");               
      i.putExtra("msg",title.getText().toString());
      i.putExtra("note", note.getText().toString());
      sendBroadcast(i);
```

and specify this action in manifest file which is your receiver like this

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="my.action.string" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now make change your receiver code with code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
       if(intent.getAction().equals("my.action.string"))
       {     

       SharedPreferences  sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCESS, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // get your intent which you have passed in receiver 

      String msg=intent.getStringExtra("msg");
   //  Now save your string with shared preference
      sharedpreferences.edit().putString("msg1",msg).commit();

      String note=intent.getStringExtra("note");
      sharedpreferences.edit().putString("note1",note).commit();
     }

 // now get your sharedpreference String  with boot complete

 // and start activity with passing your string data

     if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
     {
        // get the sharedpreference string and pass it with intent
        // to alarmDialog.class

        String message = sharedpreference.getString("msg1",msg1);          
        String notes = sharedpreference.getString("note1",note1);
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, alarmDialog.class);                                
        startIntent.putExtra("msg",message);
        startIntent.putExtra("note",notes);

        //startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(startIntent);

   }`
}`
```

You have set action `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`, With above code you your sharedpreference string get and pass with intent to `alarmDialog.class` when your device boot is complete.

you have specified this action in your manifest file so now no need to do second time.  try this code.
Try this .

Comment: I think you are right that was what i thought. But i cannot store them in SharedPreference  cause i have some alarms...The application is TO DO LIST ...I am losing my mind, what can i do?Thank you.

Comment: Maybe i can move my Strings by setAction and get them in receiver by getAction?

Comment: I didn't understand the meaning of the code... Intent i1= new Intent(context, PendingIntent.class);
     i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN"); and are you sure the code help?i see it's just filter the Exceptions

Comment: its receive context of Pendingintent classs and start Pending activity with  screen on.

Comment: Now i see that the application causes error every time after the phone opens...it is not about the receiver...

Comment: Apparently the error was what you say...the receiver can't get the strings and i get error NullPointerException...your solution doesn't work...what can i do?Thank you

Comment: @user3997118 i have made changes with code try this code. if i am not wrong then you want to start alarmDailog class with String data which are passing with receiver.

Comment: i have error- when i turns on my phone the app crash by the receiver in the manifest(i think you code is fine). Can i use the dynamically way?

Comment: @peter  Now you need to create one service class and register your `AlarmReceiver.class` in that service. Now start your service with set alarm and stop your service with destroy or stop alarm. Just create one Service class and register receiver. i hope your app will work fine.

Comment: i don't think your code will work...i have some alarms and you store just last alarm in sharedpreferences...Am i right?

Comment: @user3997118. I have passed only two shared preference string. if you have array then you can pass array with shared preference or create DB.    And you can chane this code as you want with multiple array. try to do this.

Comment: I add every time alarms so the index changes everytime  and i cannot move everytime new array to sharedpreferences because i dont have index for the array...sharedpreferences does not working and DB too